# Disable XSD validation for a single element?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have one XSD file, which contains some element

```
<xs:element name="BasicData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="TTTeacherList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="NonTeachingActivityList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="TTStudentList" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> 

<xs:element name="NonTeachingActivityList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="NonTeachingActivity" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="NonTeachingActivity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="NTCode" type="String10"/>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="String100"/>
                <xs:element name="Type" type="MeetingType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="RefId" type="GUID" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want remove all the validation of element `NonTeachingActivity` such that whether it  occurs or not, it will be never check validation. And I won't remove whole element just ignore this element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support in XSD for what you ask, but here are two options:

1. If you want `NonTeachingActivity`'s content model not to be
   validated, you can vacate it,

   ```
   <xs:element name="NonTeachingActivity"/>
   ```

   then it will be allowed to contain any XML.
2. If you want `NonTeachingActivity`'s appearance in the content model
   of other elements not to affect validation, you can attempt to
   replace references to `NonTeachingActivity` with

   ```
   <xs:any processContents="skip" />
   ```

   and, provided you've not created a parsing ambiguity, this will
   allow any element to appear in its place.

Option #1, combined with making `NonTeachingActivity` optional anywhere used, is probably closest to meeting your requirements.

Comment: I want to ignore this element validation, either occurs or not in xml file.

Comment: @Gabu: Your comment fails to address the new information I've provided you in this answer; it merely restates your original request.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the "any" tag:

```
<xs:element name="NonTeachingActivityList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```